# disable data when condition success in gridview cell values C#

Tags: jquery, gridview

Here is the table

```
<div id="table">
<table id="grdCompanyData">
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td class="fa-plus">d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>r</td>
  <td class="fa-plus">d</td>
</tr> 
</div>
```

i am trying to disable the last cell value "d" if the third cell value is "c"..

here is the code i am trying

```
$("[id*=grdCompanyData]").find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
                var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                    isActiveStatus = $tds.eq(3).text();
                var string = $.trim(isActiveStatus.replace(/[\t\n]+/g, ' '));
                debugger
                if (string == "c") {
                    $('.fa-plus').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
```

here the class for last column td ("d") is compalsary and i cont change...

i am getting that the second row last coulmn with disabled as well.. how to restrict it to condition...

thank you...

Comment: instead of `$('.fa-plus').attr("disabled", "disabled");`; go for `$(this).find('.fa-plus').attr("disabled", "disabled");`. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things were wrong in the code. The name of classes should be `"fa-plus"` not `".fa-plus"`

I think you did the confusion with jQuery selector which is `.fa-plus`.

It's `$tds.eq(2).text()` to get the third td, it start with index 0.

Also don't forget to close the `table` tag in your HTML code.

Then use `$(this).find('.fa-plus').attr("disabled", "disabled");` to find the `td` element to apply the attr disabled.

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/fdhvq0zy/2/)